# How to correctly mutate dates in R?

Tags: r, date, dplyr, case

I'm trying to make the column `fecha` a date column. I have two formats of date as you see below.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  fecha = c("41232", "dic-11")
)

#months
meses <- c("ene", "feb", "mar", "abr", "may", "jun", "jul", "ago", "set", "oct", "nov", "dic")
```

I've created a function to make this kind of format `dic-11` a date which seems to work.

```
obtener_fecha <- function(x) {
  
  ano <- str_extract(x, "\\d\\d$") %>% 
    parse_number() %>% 
    `+`(2000)
  
  mes <- str_which(meses, str_remove(x, "-\\d\\d$"))
  
  lubridate::make_date(year = ano, month = mes, day = 1)

}
```

with `openxlsx::convertToDate(parse_number(x))` you can parse a date like `"41232"`.

Now, I used `case_when` to make this work, but it throws an error.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(fecha_2 = case_when(
    str_detect(fecha, "-\\d\\d$") ~ lubridate::as_date(map_dbl(fecha, function(x) obtener_fecha(x))),
    str_detect(fecha, "^\\d{5}") ~ openxlsx::convertToDate(parse_number(df$fecha)),
  ))
```

error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `fecha_2 = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error:
! error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as_date': Result 1 must be a single double, not a vector of class `Date` and of length 0
```

I know that:

```
map(df$fecha, function(x) obtener_fecha(x)) equals

[[1]]
Date of length 0

[[2]]
[1] "2011-12-01"
```

How to make this list a vector of Dates with NAs and be in a column made by `case_when`?

Desired output:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  fecha  fecha_2   
  <chr>  <date>    
1 41232  2012-11-19
2 dic-11 2011-12-01
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by using `as.Date(NA)` in the `else` part

```
obtener_fecha <- function(x) {
  
  if (str_detect(x, "-\\d\\d$")) {
  ano <- str_extract(x, "\\d\\d$") %>% 
    parse_number() %>% 
    `+`(2000)
  
  mes <- str_which(meses, str_remove(x, "-\\d\\d$"))
  
  lubridate::make_date(year = ano, month = mes, day = 1)
  } else {
    as.Date(NA)
  }

}
```